# I want to remove app.php from url, but how?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have a symfony project and I uploaded it to my host. Here is my folders order:

```
www
-------vendor
-------bin
-------src
-------app
-------html
--------------(my web content is inside html folder including .htaccess)
--------------app.php
```

When I type `ip_address/app.php` in browser it brings my homepage. But I want to remove `app.php` from all request urls. Please help me to do that.

I searched for solutions but because I don't know anything about apache configuration I couldn't solve my problem.

Please give me an straight solution or a complete code for `.htaccess`.

Comment: `DirectoryIndex app.php`, basically

Comment: It is as you mentioned but not work. I think apache does not use of .htaccess !

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of vhost for Symfony in the last versions of Apache:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/my-app.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app.local.fr
    DocumentRoot /home/me/Workspace/MySymfonyApp/web

    <Directory /home/me/Workspace/MySymfonyApp/web>
            Options Includes FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride none
            Require all granted
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_app_error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_app_access.log vhost_combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Note the three lines which are the ones that will "remove" `app.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

To active this url rewriting for all your vhosts, you have to execute the following commands:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

*Finally, I wouldn't recomment to use `.htaccess` because of associated security problems.*

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `.htaccess` file to your webspace. There is the rewrite to app.php.

```
# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+app\.php([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^$ /app.php [L]
```

Comment: I have some confusing about my .htaccess. It does not matter whether I put .htaccess to my html folder or not. Even when I change it I can't see any changes in my websites behavior. Should I do anything else further than changing the .htaccess of html folder?

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want is that when you load `http://ip_address` you want the content in `html/app.php` to get loaded. This you can do with `DirectoryIndex` directive. More information about this can be [found here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php app.php
```

The above configuration will make apache to search for `index.html` file first, `index.php` file second and the `app.php` third. If it finds any of these files then it will be loaded.

You can add this directive withing `<VirtualHost>` section if you want different behavior for different virtual hosts.

Comment: My current directoryIndex is : DirectoryIndex app.php. But it does not work

Comment: Can you post the absolute path of `DocumentRoot` and that of the `app.php`.

Comment: /var/www/html/app.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of my friends here. I solved my problem by allowing override with `AllowOverride All` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file.